# How can I use oh-my-zsh with PHPStorm?

Tags: zsh, phpstorm

I just got [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) (a very good command line utility) and would like to utilize this within the PHPStorm terminal.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As *oh-my-zsh* is more of an extended zsh-configuration, it should be sufficient to just tell PHPStorm to use `zsh` as Shell. This can be done in the *Settings* dialog (Menu *File*->*Settings*) under section *Project Settings*->*Terminal*. Just change *Shell Path* to the path of `zsh` (can be found out with `type zsh` in a terminal).

To affect every (new) project you may have to repeat this in *File*->*Default Settigs*

Comment: Mine is getting reset to `/bin/bash` after I restart the WebStorm. Any idea why?

Comment: @Vivek Maybe your configuration files - either project or global - are write-protected. Otherwise nothing comes to mind immediately. Maybe it would be better, if you you created a new question. I doubt that to many will actually see this comment on an old answer. Maybe also check the IntelliJ bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: Any idea why the theme is so different and looks so bad?

Answer (score 20):

For once and all setup:

Set it in Preferences->Tools->Terminal and Shell Path = `/bin/zsh`

restart your PhpStorm and thats it.

Comment: Not working for Windows, it results onerror `java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY`

Comment: Mine correctly says it's using /bin/zsh but the bahvouir seems limited compare with the actual terminal, for instance the ALT+ [arrow left] keys do not skip words

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10